# Open a url response in the browser

Tags: python, bots

I'm writing a script that makes a post request to a url, I'd then like to open the response page in the browser of the system. I'm having trouble finding out how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could save the content to a local file and use `webbrowser.open_new("file://yourlocalfile.html")` but this has one major flaw:

Because of the browsers same origin policy this site could not load any external js, css or pictures.

Comment: This is the solution I ended up going for. It's not ideal but it got the job done.

Answer (score 0):

use [webbrowser](https://docs.python.org/2/library/webbrowser.html) to open browser:

```
webbrowser.open(url, new=0, autoraise=True)
webbrowser.open_new(url)
webbrowser.open_new_tab(url)
```

Update: the url is the local path of the response page file: `file://path/file.html`

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question, I'm receiving a response from a post request, so there is no URL to use in this case.

Comment: Note: This way the output of the post request cannot be processed in python.

Comment: @user2320239 url is created dir the path of response file. I should have been more specific.

Comment: @SimonKirsten proceeding process is not required in this case.